# jQuery UI Datepicker disable all days before certain date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there any way of using the `minDate` in order to disable all days before a certain date? I know I can use `minDate: 0` to disable all days before the current date, but I need to specificy a date and disable all dates before that date.

I could also use showDaysBefore but I think I will have to define a list of all days I want to disable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify like this

```
 minDate: new Date(1999, 10, 25),
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is it possible to ``setDate`` to let's say June 2013 but have the minDate defined to August 2013? I'm trying to do that and it doesn't work for some reason. The expected behavior is to see the datepicker with the correct month (June) and all dates should be disabled (since the mindate is August)

Comment: @hoverhand sorry i dont have idea on that